# jQuery change CSS on click not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class="exp-col-content-holder">
    <a class="expand-content-link" href="#">test</a>
       <div class="hidden-content">
          <p class="hiddenContentp">testttttt</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the CSS of an element on click. When I click the button everything funs except for the last bit `.css("display","block");` This never changes from `display:none` to `display:block`.

```
jQuery(this).toggleClass("opened").parent(".exp-col-content-holder").find(".hidden-content").stop().slideToggle("slow").css("display","block");
```

Did I write the jQuery wrong?

The display doesn't set to block so the hidden content never becomes visible. This works on my localhost installation, but not on a live server (which is strange?).

Comment: Show all script and html please.

Comment: What's the element you want to change the display?

Comment: "This works on my localhost installation, but not on a live server" So issue is not in posted code. Check your console for error, especially see if jquery is loaded or not

Comment: Show how are you calling jquery.

Comment: I've included the html above. The jQuery is placed in the header. If I double click the link it runs as expected. Other wise just never displays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but would this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/9sk3n/

jQuery:

```
(function(){

    $( document ).on('click', '.expand-content-link', function(){
        $('.hidden-content').slideToggle("slow"); 
    });

})();
```

CSS:

```
.hidden-content{
    display:none;
}
```